# OpenCV Aruco Marker

Tags: c++, opencv, aruco

I am trying to generate Arcuo Marker and Detect the marker in Visual Studio 2019 vc16, I am using **OpenCV version 4.7** and i am using a already written code of generating Arcuo marker, in the code they have **aruco.hpp** header file but in the new version they do not have that, it is moved in the **objectdetect** folder. I am just confused that how can I use or call Arcuo, because I am not sure what was in the previous version. Any help will be appreciated.

I tried to use older version, in those I could not see aruco.hpp as well. I am confused because how it is not there while everyone is using it? what am I Missing??

Comment: In OpenCV 4.7 the ArUco module got non-compatible changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build OpenCV [with its contribs](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib).

There's also an option for that in Conan if you happen to use it.

Then `aruco.hpp` will be available [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/4.x/modules/aruco/include/opencv2).